# How do I reset the BootstrapValidator without deleting data from the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I am using [BootstrapValidator](http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/getting-started/) in a project. After the validator has been initialized `$(formSelector).bootstrapValidator(/*plugin options*/)`, other javascript may enable or disable some input fields. I need to restart the validator without clearing the input fields, so that the validator is checking all enabled fields and ignoring the disabled ones.

I have tried `$(formSelector).bootstrapValidator('resetForm', true);` after disabling/enabling fields, but this clears the data from the input fields.

If I go without resetting, the newly-enabled fields are not validated, and the disabled fields prevent submittal.

How can I restart the BootstrapValidator?

Edit: I tried the solution in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591361/revalidate-field-using-bootstrapvalidator). It did not solve the problem, presumably because the Validator wasn't acting on those fields in the first place, so it couldn't be 'reset'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved this, by first destroying the BootstrapValidator instance, and then re-initializing it.

We have a function for the initialization,

```
function initFormValidation () {
    $(formSelector).bootstrapValidator(/*plugin options*/)
}
```

after enabling/disabling input fields, we destroy the instance

```
var bootstrapValidator = $(form).data('bootstrapValidator');

if (bootstrapValidator != undefined)
    boostrapValidator.destroy();
```

and re-initialize it

```
initFormValidation();
```